# Stream zip file from server to client: No download progress

Tags: quarkus

There are quite a few articles about streaming zips from the client. I have read a lot and I will go into some of them.

This is my quarkus endpoint:

```
@GET
@Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM )
@Path( DOWNLOAD_MUSIC )
public Response downloadMusic( @QueryParam( value = ID ) Long id ) throws IOException, SystemException {
    return Response.ok(meisterschaftService.downloadMusicFromChampionship( id ) )
            .type( "application/zip" )
            .header( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"music.zip\"" )
            .build();
}
```

This is my service:

```
public StreamingOutput downloadMusicFromChampionship( Long meisterschaftId ) throws IOException {

    Meisterschaft byChampionshipId = meisterschaftDao.findById( meisterschaftId );

    List<MeisterschaftDance> meisterschaftDances = meisterschaftDanceDao.findByMeisterschaft( byChampionshipId.getId() );

    Set<Dance> taenze = meisterschaftDances.stream().map( MeisterschaftDance::getDance ).collect( Collectors.toSet() );

    StreamingOutput streamingOutput = outputStream -> {
        BufferedOutputStream baos = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream( baos );
        int test = 1;
        for (Dance einTanz : taenze) {
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry( einTanz.getTitel() + ".mp3" );
            entry.setSize( einTanz.getMp3File().length );
            zos.putNextEntry( entry );
            zos.write( einTanz.getMp3File() );
            zos.closeEntry();
            test++;
        }
        zos.close();
        zos.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    };
    return streamingOutput;
}
```

From this article I have learned that I have to make an StreamingOutput from my zip-file:
[How can i return a zip file from my java server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48120971/3371251)

On the client side I have used this stackoverflow article for my solution:
[How to download a readable stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63946003/3371251)

```
try {
    const res = await fetch('meisterschaft/downloadMusic?id=' +
        encodeURIComponent( id ), {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + keycloak.token
        }
    } );

const blob = await res.blob();
const newBlob = new Blob([blob]);

const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);

const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = blobUrl;
link.setAttribute('download', "test.zip");
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
// @ts-ignore
link.parentNode.removeChild(link);

// @ts-ignore
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blob);
} catch ( e ) {
    console.log( "Some error" )
}
```

The problem now is that I can see in the developer console that the file (approx. 4GB) is being streamed. But the Save-As dialog appears only **AFTER** the download has finished.

How can I get a download window with a progress bar right from the start? Like that one:
[image]

//EDIT
I just don't want to download the 4GB in the background and only display the Save-AS field AFTER the download. I would like to have it like in my picture above: 1MB .... 2MB .... 3MB ... and so on. It is not important how much MB overall we have.

Comment: In order to have a progress bar, you have to include the `Content-Length` header in the response. This header must be sent *before* the body begins. Of course, your code would then need to know how big the zip file is *before* it starts sending it, which means it would have to zip in-memory or in a temp file on disk.

Comment: @StephenCleary Like in my example picture (download.zip) there is also no downloadprogress. Is it anyhow possible only to show the download in the browser? I do not want to hiddenly download 4GB in the background and after download showing the SAVE-AS dialog